# event handler on silverlight out of browser uninstalling

Tags: c#, silverlight, isolatedstorage, out-of-browser, isolatedstoragefile

I am writing an application using silverlight technology.
Using the CheckAndDownloadUpdateCompleted method I can let the sdk handle automatically the update of the client.
I also see the installed "application" in the control panel. I can "uninstall" the "application"; all is fine.

but: my application make heavy usage of the Isolated Storage. As I see from my tests, if I uninstall the application the data saved into the storage is not cleaned.
Is there a way to be notified of the uninstallation and do some cleanup?

Comment: I don't think so. You can listen to `InstallStateChanged` and that will work if the user uninstalls while the app is running (via a button click, for example). But the application won't be running to hear it when the user uninstalls via "Programs and Features".